# how to handle rollback situation in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, transactions

Cassandra doesn't provide rollback transaction and ACID properties like traditional RDBMS, instead, it provides durable transactions.

This is fine if you're OK with eventual consistency or you can even tune it if want stronger consistency.

My situation is that during a long transaction there might be some exceptions due to application-level logic, in that case, I can just abort the transaction in RDBMS and the database will do the rollback for me.

If I do want the rollback feature, do I have to write the rollback code in my application on my own? Is there any tunable setting in Cassandra to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is no rollback feature in Cassandra and you will need to manage it in your code.

A straight `DELETE` would be easy to implement client-side but if you want to rollback to a previous version of the data, that will be challenging since you'll need to implement a read-before-write, i.e. read the existing version so you know what to rollback to before writing.

But in a distributed architecture with no locks/isolation, it will be difficult to know if another client updated the data after you read it. Cheers!